# Unique number from 6 different numbers <= 49 and its inverse

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I know how to compute a unique number for 6 different numbers <= 49. The algorithm is simple:

```
def number_for_selected_numbers(selected_numbers):
    selected_numbers = sorted(selected_numbers)
    result = 0
    for i, number in enumerate(selected_numbers):
        result += binomial_coefficient(49 - number, 6 - i)
    return result
```

My question is how to compute 6 different number for given number from 1...~14M (where ~14M is a number for all possible combination of 6 different numbers).

Comment: What does "newton(49 - number, 6 - i)" do?

Comment: Create a hash-table of all 14M or so combinations. Then, you can simply perform a lookup? That would be how I would do it, anyway (since like user73985, I have no idea what the newton function does).

Comment: question updated

Comment: Maybe give an example of the six numbers and what the "unique number" will be.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe that's a waste of memory I'm sure there is a formula to compute it back

Comment: number_for_selected_numbers([6,14,23,34,37,42]) -> 6436564

Comment: I need formula to compute numbers back from 6436564

Comment: Ok, I do not understand your loop. You have two variables looping, but only one set of numbers to loop through? How does Python interpret this? I'm thinking:

$$\dbinom{49-6}{6-1} + \dbinom{49-14}{6-2} + \dbinom{49-23}{6-3} + \dbinom{49-34}{6-4} + \dbinom{49-37}{6-5} + \dbinom{49-42}{6-6}$$

But this is clearly false, as the last term will always be 1, regardless of what the sixth input is. You said that the numbers generated are unique.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe nearly right, but $i$ will start at 0 and so the last term will be ${49 - 42}\choose{6-5}$

Comment: Look at [Combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). In particular, the part about National Lottery example.  If I understand it correctly,
the decoding algorithm for $$N = \sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{49-c_k}{6-k}
\quad\text{ for }\quad 1 \le c_0 < c_1 < \cdots < c_6 \le 49
$$
is $c_0$ is the smallest one such that $\binom{49-c_0}{6} \le N$, $c_1$ is the smallest $c$ such that $\binom{49-c_1}{5} \le N - \binom{49-c_0}{6}$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

For the first number, it will be the minimum value of $a$ such that $\dbinom{49-a}{6}<\text{number}$.

The second number, it will be the minimum value of $b$ such that $\dbinom{49-b}{5}<\text{number}-\dbinom{49-a}{6}$.

The third number, it will be the minimum value of $c$ such that $\dbinom{49-c}{4}<\text{number}-\dbinom{49-a}{6}-\dbinom{49-b}{5}$.

Etc.

Note:

$1\le a \le 44$

$a+1\le b \le 45$

$b+1 \le c \le 46$

$c+1\le d \le 47$

$d+1\le e\le 48$

$e+1\le f \le 49$

So, that should make your loops pretty efficient. You can just loop from 1 to 49 once and after you find all six numbers, break.